# How can this notification system be improved?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, notifications, ruby-on-rails-5, dry, maintainability

I'm looking to improve a piece of code I did. I have a notification system in place, it's working well, the problem is that's it's not DRY at all, and to maintain it's just a nightmare... I was looking for some help to get this done in a proper way and in the rails way.
Please don't be scared :)

Here is my code :

The controller :

```
class NotificationsController < ApplicationController

  def mynotifications
    @u_notifications_paginate = current_user.notifications.all.order('created_at DESC').paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
    @u_notifications_paginate.update read: true
  end

  def destroy
    if current_user
        notif = current_user.notifications.find_by_notification_uid!(params[:id])
        notif.destroy
        redirect_to mynotifications_path(locale: I18n.locale)
    else
        redirect_to root_path(locale: I18n.locale)
    end
  end

end
```

My helper :

```
module NotificationsHelper

    def user_notifications_number
        user.notifications.where(read: false).count
    end

    def user_notifications_paginate
        user.notifications.where(read: false).order('created_at DESC').last(3)
    end

    def user_notifications_exists?
        user.notifications.where(read: false).exists?
    end

    def newmember_reason?
        user.notifications.where("reason = ?", "New Member").exists?
    end

    def acceptgroup_reason?
        user.notifications.where("reason = ?", "Welcome").exists?
    end

    def deniedgroup_reason?
        user.notifications.where("reason = ?", "Denied").exists?
    end

    def new_ownership_change_reason?
        user.notifications.where("reason = ?", "New Owner").exists?
    end

    def left_ownership_change_reason?
        user.notifications.where("reason = ?", "Owner Left").exists?
    end

    def new_invitation_reason?
        user.notifications.where("reason = ?", "Group Invitation").exists?
    end

    def invitation_accepted_reason?
        user.notifications.where("reason = ?", "Accepted").exists?
    end

    def invitation_declined_reason?
        user.notifications.where("reason = ?", "Declined").exists?
    end
end
```

My view :

```
<% @u_notifications_paginate.each do |notif| %>
        <% if deniedgroup_reason? || invitation_declined_reason? %>
            <div class="notif-negative">
        <% elsif new_ownership_change_reason? || left_ownership_change_reason? %>
            <div class="notif-info">
        <% else %>
            <div class="notif-positive">
        <% end %>
                <h6 class="d-inline"><strong><%= notif.reason %></strong></h6>
                <div class="float-right d-inline"><%= notif.created_at.strftime("%A the %d/%m/%Y at %H:%M%p") %></div></br></br>
                <% if newmember_reason? %>
                    <div class="d-inline"><strong><%= notif.notified_by.name %> <%= notif.notified_by.firstname %></strong> want's to join the Group : <strong>'<%= notif.group.name %>'</strong>.</div>
                    <%= link_to deny_member_path(guid: notif.notified_by, auth_token: notif.group.auth_token, locale: I18n.locale), class: 'btn btn-danger float-right' do %>
                    <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                    <% end %>
                    <%= link_to accept_member_path(guid: notif.notified_by, auth_token: notif.group.auth_token, locale: I18n.locale), class: 'btn btn-success float-right' do %>
                    <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                    <% end %>
                <% elsif acceptgroup_reason? %>
                    <div class="d-inline">You have been accepted by <strong><%= notif.group.owner.firstname %></strong> in the Group : <strong>'<%= notif.group.name %>'</strong>.</div>
                    <%= link_to notification_path(id: notif.notification_uid, locale: I18n.locale), method: :delete, class: "btn btn-success float-right" do %>
                    <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                    <% end %>
                <% elsif deniedgroup_reason? %>
                    <div class="d-inline">You have been refused to enter the <strong>Group</strong>. 'Token' (Share Key) : <%= notif.group.auth_token %>.</div>
                    <%= link_to notification_path(id: notif.notification_uid, locale: I18n.locale), method: :delete, class: "btn btn-danger float-right" do %>
                    <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                    <% end %>
                <% elsif new_ownership_change_reason? %>
                    <div class="d-inline"><strong><%= notif.notified_by.firstname %></strong> gave you the Ownership of the Group : <strong>'<%= notif.group.name %>'</strong>.</div>
                    <%= link_to notification_path(id: notif.notification_uid, locale: I18n.locale), method: :delete, class: "btn btn-info float-right" do %>
                    <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                    <% end %>
                <% elsif left_ownership_change_reason? %>
                    <div class="d-inline"><strong><%= notif.notified_by.firstname %></strong> left the Group : <strong>'<%= notif.group.name %>'</strong> you are the new Owner.</div>
                    <%= link_to notification_path(id: notif.notification_uid, locale: I18n.locale), method: :delete, class: "btn btn-info float-right" do %>
                    <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                    <% end %>   
                <% elsif new_invitation_reason? %>
                    <div class="d-inline"><strong><%= notif.notified_by.firstname %></strong> invites you in the Group : <strong>'<%= notif.group.name %>'</strong>.</div>
                    <%= link_to deny_invitation_path(guid: notif.user, auth_token: notif.group.auth_token, locale: I18n.locale), class: 'btn btn-danger float-right' do %>
                    <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                    <% end %>
                    <%= link_to accept_invitation_path(guid: notif.user, auth_token: notif.group.auth_token, locale: I18n.locale), class: 'btn btn-success float-right' do %>
                    <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                    <% end %>
                <% elsif invitation_accepted_reason? %>
                    <div class="d-inline"><strong><%= notif.notified_by.firstname %></strong> accepted the Invitation in the Group : <strong>'<%= notif.group.name %>'</strong>.</div>
                    <%= link_to notification_path(id: notif.notification_uid, locale: I18n.locale), method: :delete, class: "btn btn-success float-right" do %>
                    <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                    <% end %>
                <% elsif invitation_declined_reason? %>
                    <div class="d-inline"><strong><%= notif.notified_by.firstname %></strong> refused the Invitation in the Group : <strong>'<%= notif.group.name %>'</strong>.</div>
                    <%= link_to notification_path(id: notif.notification_uid, locale: I18n.locale), method: :delete, class: "btn btn-danger float-right" do %>
                    <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                    <% end %>
                <% end %>
            </div></br>
    <% end %>
```

My navbar :

```
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="userNotification">
          <% user_notifications_paginate.each do |notif| %>
            <div class="dropdown-item card-pad">
                <h6 class="d-inline"><strong><%= notif.reason %></strong></h6>
                <div class="float-right d-inline"><%= notif.created_at.strftime("%d/%m/%Y") %></div>
              <% if newmember_reason? %>
                <div><strong><%= notif.notified_by.firstname %></strong> want's to join the Group : <strong>'<%= notif.group.name %>'</strong>.</div>
                <sub><%= link_to(t(".notif_readmore"), mynotifications_path(locale: I18n.locale)) %></sub>
              <% elsif acceptgroup_reason? %>
                <div>You have been accepted by <strong><%= notif.group.owner.firstname %></strong> in the Group : <strong>'<%= notif.group.name %>'</strong>.</div>
                <sub><%= link_to(t(".notif_readmore"), mynotifications_path(locale: I18n.locale)) %></sub>
              <% elsif deniedgroup_reason? %>
                <div>You have been refused to enter the <strong>Group</strong>.</div>
                <sub><%= link_to(t(".notif_readmore"), mynotifications_path(locale: I18n.locale)) %></sub>
              <% elsif new_ownership_change_reason? %>
                <div>You are the new Owner of the Group : <strong>'<%= notif.group.name %>'</strong>.</div>
                <sub><%= link_to(t(".notif_readmore"), mynotifications_path(locale: I18n.locale)) %></sub>
              <% elsif left_ownership_change_reason? %>
                <div><strong><%= notif.notified_by.firstname %></strong> left the Group : <strong>'<%= notif.group.name %>'</strong> you are the new Owner.</div>
                <sub><%= link_to(t(".notif_readmore"), mynotifications_path(locale: I18n.locale)) %></sub>
              <% elsif new_invitation_reason? %>
                <div><strong><%= notif.notified_by.firstname %></strong> invites you in the Group : <strong>'<%= notif.group.name %>'</strong>.</div>
                <sub><%= link_to(t(".notif_readmore"), mynotifications_path(locale: I18n.locale)) %></sub>
              <% elsif invitation_accepted_reason? %>
                <div><strong><%= notif.notified_by.firstname %></strong> accepted the Invitation in the Group : <strong>'<%= notif.group.name %>'</strong>.</div>
                <sub><%= link_to(t(".notif_readmore"), mynotifications_path(locale: I18n.locale)) %></sub>
              <% elsif invitation_declined_reason? %>
                <div><strong><%= notif.notified_by.firstname %></strong> refused the Invitation in the Group : <strong>'<%= notif.group.name %>'</strong>.</div>
                <sub><%= link_to(t(".notif_readmore"), mynotifications_path(locale: I18n.locale)) %></sub>
              <% end %>
              <hr class="col-5">
            </div>
          <% end %>
            <% if user_notifications_exists? %>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <%= link_to(t(".notif_showall"), mynotifications_path(locale: I18n.locale), class: 'dropdown-item center') %>
            <% else %>
              <div class="center"><%= t(".notif_no_notif") %></div>
            <% end %>
        </div>
```

I'm so ashame to show that really...

Anyway what I have here, is that basically if a user has a notification, a popup is showed in the navbar, you can then click on the notification and read it in the view. As soon as the user comes in the view the notification is read (toggle boolean).
To create a notification I use this :

```
Notification.create!(read: false, user_id: user.id, notified_by_id: group.owner.id, group_id: group.id, reason: "Welcome")
```

This piece of code for example is in my controller that handle the membership, this one, more specifically, is to add a member, and this notification is created to notify the user that he has been accepted in the group.

I think you can see my problem and it is quite obvious. I'm playing with the condition in my view to call the good "reason" and so, display the right text according to that. I'm repeating my code several times, it is really horrible, I know. My question is how could I improve that. I'm not looking for a straight up answer or code, I'm just wondering how I could do that better and if you guys have some tricks to make this able to maintain.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can start with fixing indentation of your code. (ERB posted here seems to be okey-ish, but the controller....). This alone will give this code +10 points to maintainability. :)

Comment: Sorry if it is a little messy. I should call something else than Notification.all ? Maybe if I get the Notification.where("reason = ?" .... in the controller and in my view I loop through each of them ?

Comment: You don't need `.all` there, btw.

Comment: yeah .. true... I'm not a pro sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple yet effective idea: don't hardcode the link between notification and its html representation. Instead, let notifications themselves define how they should render. For example, let each notification have a field `partial_name`.

```
<Notification id: 1, partial_name: 'newmember', ...>
<Notification id: 2, partial_name: 'accept_group', ...>
```

then you extract the corresponding partials

#### views/notifications/types/_newmember.html.erb

```
<div><strong><%= notif.notified_by.firstname %></strong> want's to join the Group : <strong>'<%= notif.group.name %>'</strong>.</div>
<sub><%= link_to(t(".notif_readmore"), mynotifications_path(locale: I18n.locale)) %></sub>
```

then your loop becomes REALLY simple:

```
<% user_notifications_paginate.each do |notif| %>
  <%= render partial: "notifications/types/#{notif.partial_name}", locals: { notif: notif } %>
<% end %>
```

I might have missed a few tiny details, but this is the general idea.

Comment: wow ok, very nice. I could actually use my reason field instead of doing new field `partial_name` right ? Thanks I see where you want to go with this, I will give a try

Comment: @Asso: ah yes, you can totally reuse your `reason` field.

Comment: @Asso: JFYI, you _don't_ have to prefix all your questions with "rails 5.1" (unless the question is really REALLY specific to this version, which is not the case for all of your past questions). Plus, people will know you're using rails 5 from the tag, `[ruby-on-rails-5]`.

Comment: I have a lot of things to modify but it works so well, thank you very much !

Comment: Thanks for the tip ;)